# Show Form based on input?

Tags: javascript

Having a hard time showing a certain form depending on the input selected from a drop down menu. Here is my current code which does not seem to be working.

HTML

```
<form id="form-shower">
<select id="myselect">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
<option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
<option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<form name="form_name1" id="form_name1" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form name="form_name2" id="form_name2" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>

<form name="form_name3" id="form_name3" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 3---->
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myselect").on("change", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript demo:

- Reference the select element with `getElementById()`
- `addEventListener` to select for the `change` event
- When the user selects a form from select's options, `pickForm()` is called.
- `pickForm()` will:

  - store the value of the selected option in a variable.

    - `var pick = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`
  - use the value to reference the specific hidden form.

    - `var form = document.getElementById(pick);`
  - gather all the forms with an id that has the word "formName" in it.

    - `var formAll = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="formName"]');`
  - iterate through them and remove the class `.show` and add `.hide` to each.

    - `for(var i=0; i < formAll.length; i++) {
      formAll[i].classList.remove('show');
      formAll[i].classList.add('hide');
      }`
  - remove class `.hide` and add `.show` to the chosen form

    - `form.classList.remove('hide');
      form.classList.add('show');`

Here's a jQuery demo:

```
$('#ySelect').on('change', function(event) {
   var pick = event.target.value;
   var $pick = $('#'+pick);
   $('[id*="formName"]').hide();
   $pick.show();
});
```

### SNIPPET

```js
//JavaScript
var sel = document.getElementById('xSelect');

sel.addEventListener('change', pickForm, false);

function pickForm(e) {
  var pick = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var form = document.getElementById(pick);
  var formAll = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="formName"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < formAll.length; i++) {
    formAll[i].classList.remove('show');
    formAll[i].classList.add('hide');
  }
  form.classList.remove('hide');
  form.classList.add('show');
}

//jQuery

$('#ySelect').on('change', function(event) {
  var pick = event.target.value;
  var $pick = $('#' + pick);
  $('[id*="formname"]').hide();
  $pick.show();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
[id*="formName"] {
  color: red;
}
[id*="formname"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formSelect">
  <label>JavaScript</label>
  <select id="xSelect">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="formName1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="formName2">Form 2</option>
    <option value="formName3">Form 3</option>
  </select>


  <label>jQuery</label>
  <select id="ySelect">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="formname1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="formname2">Form 2</option>
    <option value="formname3">Form 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
<section id="js">
  <form name="formName1" id="formName1" class="hide">
    FORM 1
  </form>

  <form name="formName2" id="formName2" class="hide">
    FORM 2
  </form>

  <form name="formName3" id="formName3" class="hide">
    FORM 3
  </form>
</section>

<section id="jq">
  <form name="formname1" id="formname1" class="hide">
    FORM 1
  </form>

  <form name="formName2" id="formname2" class="hide">
    FORM 2
  </form>

  <form name="formname3" id="formname3" class="hide">
    FORM 3
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the forms with divs and handle with classes and ids:

```
<form id="form-shower">
<select id="myselect">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
<option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
<option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="form_name1" class="forms">
<form name="form_name1" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>
</div>

<div id="form_name2" class="forms">
<form name="form_name2" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>
</div>

<div id="form_name3" class="forms">
<form name="form_name3" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 3---->
</form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#myselect").on("change", function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $(".forms").hide();
    $("#" + selected).show();
})
```